# Facing error in Cpanel

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1

[image]Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/vvamic/public_html/www.shopperz.biz/app/autoload.php on line 40

Comment: can you please upload fulle code in question, so that someone will help you....

Comment: Are you sure, that you screenshot do not contain confidential data?

Comment: can you please upload code of `autoload.php`.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is Magento 2 autoload (although you tagged both 1.9 and 2 and 2.1, so it's a guess).  The newer versions of PHP allow arrays to be defined with a "shorthand" syntax of just square brackes: `[]`.  On the last line of `app/autoload.php` the bootstrapper populates the autoload stuff and an empty array is the second parameter:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::populateAutoloader(BP, []);
```

This new syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

I would check the version of PHP being utilized by your server.  If it's 5.3, you will need to upgrade it.